# Why can't I award a bounty to an existing answer immediately?

Tags: support, bounties

I just put a 50 reputation bounty and selected `Award an existing answer` but it won't let me award the existing answer for 24 hours.  Because the answer is there, how come I can't award it immediately?

Perhaps this is a bug?